# expo IOS build failing

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

is there a reason i keep getting this error when i run eas build --platform ios i checked my code and ./Dashboard/Réclamations exists indeed and works fine plus the android build was succesful:

```
❌ Metro encountered an error:
Unable to resolve module ./Dashboard/Réclamations from /Users/expo/workingdir/build/screens/index.js:

None of these files exist:
  * screens/Dashboard/Réclamations(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * screens/Dashboard/Réclamations/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  14 | import CreateProject from "./Dashboard/CreateProject";
  15 | import ProductDetails from "./Dashboard/ProductDetails";
> 16 | import Réclamations from "./Dashboard/Réclamations";
     |                           ^
  17 | import Contrats from "./Dashboard/Contrats";
  18 | import Compte from "./Dashboard/Compte";
  19 | import NewReclamation from "./Dashboard/NewReclamation";
```

Comment: Probably because of `É` symbol in Réclamations, just a few programming languages have full support of UTF-8 symbols. You need to change it every occurence to simple `E`

Comment: yeah that was it i removed it and it worked fine thank you